# JPA how to configure outer join with InheritanceType.JOINED

Tags: inheritance, jpa, outer-join

I have a domain model with InheritanceType.JOINED.

```
@Table(name = "S_MC_CC_RAPPORTI")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "COD_TIPORAPPORTO")
public class RapportoImpl implements Rapporto, Cloneable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COD_RAPPORTO")
    protected Long codiceRapporto;
```

and the subclass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARTE")
@DiscriminatorValue("4 ")
public class CartaImpl extends RapportoImpl implements Carta, Cloneable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1723366781345274590L;
```

This works great until the DB is consistent.

Table **Rapporto**

```
Id   COD_TIPORAPPORTO
1       4
```

Table **Carte**

```
Id   Description
1     Carta
```

So when I load a `Rapporto` by id 1 all works great. But when the db goes inconsistent all works bad.
Imagine that I have no more the record on the child table `Carte`. When I try to load it I get a `null` object because JPA makes an inner join between super and child table.
Is it possible to make configure it in a way to make an outer join on the child table

Comment: So this is a situation in which the parent table have row with particular ID but there is no child table row which have the FK to the parent row?

Comment: Yes, this is the situation. I have to handle situations like these on my production environment.

Comment: Can executing a query which asks particularly for superclass be helpful?

Comment: I'm querying on entitymanager for the superclass ase described below: 'RapportoImpl rapportoImpl = entityManager.find(RapportoImpl.class, 5l);
  assertNotNull(rapportoImpl);'

Comment: and `rapportoImpl` is null in such case?

Comment: _and rapportoImpl is null in such case?_ Yes, also coding against JPQL does the join on the subclass and return null object. `Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select r from RapportoImpl r WHERE r.codiceRapporto = :codiceRapporto");` This is the relative sql generated: `SELECT DISTINCT COD_TIPORAPPORTO FROM S_MC_CC_RAPPORTI WHERE (COD_RAPPORTO = ?)` `SELECT * FROM S_MC_CC_RAPPORTI t0, S_MC_CC_CCCLIENTI t1 WHERE (((t0.COD_RAPPORTO = ?) AND (t1.COD_RAPPORTO = t0.COD_RAPPORTO)) AND (t0.COD_TIPORAPPORTO = ?))` The problem is with the join condition. It should be a left outer join on child.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5572/discussion-between-piotr-nowicki-and-massimo-ugues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up - if your JPA provider is EclipseLink than [there is a way](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Inheritance#Outer_Joining_Subclasses) to say that it should use OUTER JOINs when fetching child objects in join inheritance strategy.

Comment: Note that this is for querying root or branch classes with subclasses, not a specific class, so is probably not ideal.  You may try, http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/SecondaryTable#Advanced_Multiple_Table_Configuration, but in general, you should consider changing you model or fixing your data